# validModesForFontPanel never called

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfontpanel, nsfontmanager

I have an application where I use the `NSFontPanel`.
I open the font panel like this:

```
NSFontManager *fontManager = [NSFontManager sharedFontManager];
[fontManager orderFrontFontPanel:self];
[fontManager setDelegate:self];
[fontManager setTarget:self];
[fontManager setAction:@selector(changeFont:)];
```

I then have an `-(void)changeFont:(id)sender` method which reacts to font changes in the panel. This all works well.

Now, I want to disable some of the font options, so I implement the `validModesForFontPanel` method of the `NSFontPanelValidation` protocol:

```
- (NSUInteger)validModesForFontPanel:(NSFontPanel *)fontPanel {
    NSLog(@"validModesForFontPanel");
    return NSFontPanelFaceModeMask | NSFontPanelCollectionModeMask | NSFontPanelSizeModeMask;
}
```

However, the method never gets called.
In the documentation it says: "*This message is sent up the responder chain to the first responder implementing the method. Ideally that object should be the first responder found that also implements changeFont:.*"

I do implement `changeFont` in this responder, so unless there is some other responder which I am not aware of, I don't know what happens to this message.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You arent indicating any responder for the panel, just for the manager.
this should do it:

```
NSFontPanel* fontPanel = [fontManager fontPanel:YES];
[fontPanel setDelegate:self];    
[fontPanel makeKeyAndOrderFront:sender];
```

Comment: Hi JPed, thank you for your reply. It was my understanding that everything went through the `NSFontManager`, but I guess I was wrong. Anyway, the code above does not work as `NSFontPanel`'s delegate must be an instance of `NSWindowDelegate`, and `self` is a subclass of `NSViewController`. It gives me this warning: `warning: sending 'TextViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<NSWindowDelegate>'`

Comment: Hi again. I was a bit to quick when I said it didn't work. It actually does, in spite of the fact that I get the warning. Is this something you have encountered?

Comment: I finally figured it out. The warning came because my class wasn't implementing the `NSWindowDelegate` protocol. I just wish all of this was a little better documented. Anyway, thank you for your answer, it did the trick :D

Comment: This solution works, but `validModesForFontPanel` gets called many many times while the font panel is open - add an `NSLog` in it to see that happens.

Comment: this is great. But I don't get it... so many comments about it working and I am the first to vote this up?